# Comparing Strings and Returning Boolean

Tags: java, string, compare, scalability, equality

I am currently working on one of the usecases where you are given 6 strings which has 3 oldValues and 3 newValues like given below:

```
String oldFirstName = "Yogend"
String oldLastName = "Jos"
String oldUserName = "YNJos"
String newFirstName = "Yogendra"
String newLastName ="Joshi"
String newUserName = "YNJoshi"
```

now what I basically want to do is compare each of the oldValue with its corresponding new value and return true if  they are not equal i.e

```
if(!oldFirstName.equalsIgnoreCase(newFirstName)) {
  return true;
}
```

Now, since I am having 3 fields and it could very well happen that in future we might have more Strings with old and new value I am looking for an optimum solution which could work in all cases no matter how many old and new values are added and without having gazillions of if else clauses.

One possibility I thought was of having Old values as **OldArrayList** and new values as **newArraylist** and then use removeAll where it would remove the duplicate values but that is not working in some cases.

Can anyone on stack help me out with some pointers on how to optimum way get this done.

Thanks,
Yogendra N Joshi

Comment: store each OldValues and NewValues in an ArrayList, so you can keep some relation between them. And then you just compare the same in index both arrayList as you are now doing. Thus, you will have one if-else, but just loop through the arrayList.

Comment: First thing : `return !oldFirstName.equalsIgnoreCase(newFirstName)` is sufficient.

Comment: @benzonico --"...without having gazillions of if else clauses..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `HashMap<yourFieldName, yourFieldValue>` instead of two `Array`s / `List`s / `Set`s of `String`s (or multiple random Strings);

Then you need a method to compare each value of both maps by their keys;

The result will be an `HashMap<String,Boolean>` containing the name of each field key, and true if the value is equal in both maps, while false if it is different.

**No matter how many fields you will add in the future, the method won't change, while the result will.**

> ***Running Example: https://ideone.com/dIaYsK***

Code

```
private static Map<String,Boolean> scanForDifferences(Map<String,Object> mapOne, 
                                                      Map<String,Object> mapTwo){

    Map<String,Boolean> retMap = new HashMap<String,Boolean>(); 
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = mapOne.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Object> entry = (Map.Entry<String,Object>)it.next();
        if (mapTwo.get(entry.getKey()).equals(entry.getValue()))
            retMap.put(entry.getKey(), new Boolean(Boolean.TRUE));
        else 
            retMap.put(entry.getKey(), new Boolean(Boolean.FALSE));
        it.remove(); // prevent ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    return retMap;
}
```

Test Case Input

```
Map<String,Object> oldMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Map<String,Object> newMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

oldMap.put("initials","Y. J.");
oldMap.put("firstName","Yogend");
oldMap.put("lastName","Jos");
oldMap.put("userName","YNJos");
oldMap.put("age","33");

newMap.put("initials","Y. J.");
newMap.put("firstName","Yogendra");
newMap.put("lastName","Joshi");
newMap.put("userName","YNJoshi");        
newMap.put("age","33");
```

Test Case Run

```
Map<String,Boolean> diffMap = Main.scanForDifferences(oldMap, newMap);

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> it = diffMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry = (Map.Entry<String,Boolean>)it.next();
    System.out.println("Field [" + entry.getKey() +"] is " +
                        (entry.getValue()?"NOT ":"") + "different" );
}
```

You should check too if a value is present in one map and not in another one.

You could return an ENUM instead of a Boolean with something like **`EQUAL`**, **`DIFFERENT`**, **`NOT PRESENT`** ...

Comment: Wohooo! This is definitely a well thought code Andrea. Totally love it. Thanks for providing suggestions and the actual code as well. This will definitely help me to write efficient and scalable code. Best, Yogendra

Answer (score 2):

you can use lambdaj ([download here](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar),[website](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)) and hamcrest ([download here](http://hamcrest.googlecode.com/files/hamcrest-1.3.zip),[website](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)), this libraries are very powerfull for managing collections, the following code is very simple and works perfectly:

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.filter;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.having;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isIn;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> oldNames =  Arrays.asList("nameA","nameE","nameC","namec","NameC");
        List<String> newNames = Arrays.asList("nameB","nameD","nameC","nameE");

        List<String> newList = filter(having(on(String.class), isIn(oldNames)),newNames);
        System.out.print(newList);  
        //print nameC, nameE
    }
}
```

With this libraries you can solve your problem in one line. You must add to your project: hamcrest-all-1.3.jar and lambdaj-2.4.jar Hope this help serve.

NOTE: This will help you assuming you can have alternatives to your code.

Comment: and this will get the team used to the power of LambdaJ coming up in newer versions of Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your String to some Set.

One set for OLD and another for NEW. And your goal of varity number of elements will also be resolved using same.

As it's set order of it will be same.

Comment: why is set better than arrayList? Or why not a hashMap, with key-values.

Comment: @Bill I think he can use ArrayList too. As per the example he gave, I don't think key,value pair is needed for it.

Comment: yes, agreed. Otherwise OP has to keep track of what an index means. Key-Value will take care of this. Just another option to think about :)